# How to specify rotation origin in openscad

Tags: openscad

OpenSCAD has `rotate` function which rotates the body around its origin axis.

Is there a way to specify an arbitrary axis?

For example, this rotates a cylinder around its center:

```
rotate(a=[90,0,0]) {
  cylinder(h=10,r1=10,r2=10);
}
```

How to make it rotate around its edge?

Comment: Found a duplicate on stackooverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45826208/openscad-rotating-around-a-particular-point

Answer (score 2):

`rotate()` always rotates around the origin of the object following it.
What you can do is to move your cylinder *away* from the origin, like this:

```
rotate(a=[90,0,0]) {
  translate([0,10,0]) cylinder(h=10,r1=10,r2=10);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following module in your code to achieve what you wish:

```
module myrotate(a, orig) {
    translate(orig)
    rotate(a)
    translate(-orig)
    children();
}

myrotate([0,0,90], [0, 10, 0]) {
    cube([10, 10, 25]);
}

myrotate([0,0,-90], [0, 10, 0]) {
    cube([10, 10, 25]);
}

color([1, 0, 0])
cube([10, 10, 25]);
```